# How to set compiler flag in VS 2005?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

How to set compiler flag (in my case `-DWITH_OPENSSL`) in Visual studio 2005? I am trying to find it in Project Properties-> Configuration Properties -> C/C++, but unsuccessfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Visual Studio 2005 with me but it should be the same with the latest version... Go to Project Properties-> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor.

In the field Preprocessor Definitions, add `WITH_OPENSSL` in the existing definitions, separated by a `;`. Don't add the switch, `-D`, Visual Studio will add it for you.